# How to parse text and number using substring in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, parsing

I have thousands of records now and I am web scrapping from web site and names comes only first name or first and second name currently as: Souleymane Doukara 85 Souza 25 Souza 59 Stefano Okaka 16 Tayfur Bingol 53 Tayfur Bingol 67 Y. Sari 90 Younes Belhanda 46

I have table records in mysql as:

Table:

| scorera |
| --- |
| M. Ozil 50 |
| M. Ozil 40 |
| M. Ozil 46 |
| M. Ozil 31 |
| M. Ozil 30 |

I wrote below query and I got results also below:

```
select
SUBSTRING(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`scorera`, '  ', 1)), 1) AS 'Player',
SUBSTRING(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`scorera`, ' ', -1)), 1) AS 'Goal Minute'
from goals;
```

| Player | Goal Minute |
| --- | --- |
| M. Ozil 50 | 50 |
| M. Ozil 40 | 40 |
| M. Ozil 46 | 46 |
| M. Ozil 31 | 31 |
| M. Ozil 30 | 30 |

If I use one more blank first substring line as shown *

```
select
SUBSTRING(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`scorera`, '  * ', 1)), 1) AS 'Player',
SUBSTRING(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`scorera`, ' ', -1)), 1) AS 'Goal Minute'
from goals;
```

I got below result as player has first name only:

| Player | Goal Minute |
| --- | --- |
| M. | 50 |
| M. | 40 |
| M. | 46 |
| M. | 31 |
| M. | 30 |

How can I get correct names when player has first or first and second names as below?

| Player | Goal Minute |
| --- | --- |
| M. Ozil | 50 |
| M. Ozil | 40 |
| M. Ozil | 46 |
| M. Ozil | 31 |
| M. Ozil | 30 |

Thanks for your help.

Names comes only `first name` or `first and second name` currently as:

```
Souleymane Doukara 85 
Souza 25 
Souza 59 
Stefano Okaka 16
Tayfur Bingol 53
Tayfur Bingol 67 
Y. Sari 90 
Younes Belhanda 46
```

Comment: Is it too late to fix the design so that the data is stored in a more usable way?

Comment: No, I have thousands of records now and I am web scrapping from web site and names comes only first name or first and second name currently as: Souleymane Doukara 85
Souza 25
Souza 59
Stefano Okaka 16
Tayfur Bingol 53
Tayfur Bingol 67
Y. Sari 90
Younes Belhanda 46

Comment: That is going to make the string manipulation more complex, I see brackets in there now that you didnt mention in the question. What else could this string look like.

Comment: I already removed brackets as : String scorera = golmin.replaceAll("[()]", ""); in my code. Only need to parse name and numbers into two columns in mysql.

Comment: PS: Really Relevant Information like that should have been in, or added to, The Question

Comment: I already mentioned what I need I guess. Anyway no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the part before the first digit as player name then this should work:

```
select RTRIM(LEFT(scorera, (REGEXP_INSTR(scorera, '[0-9]')-1))) AS `Player`,
SUBSTRING(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`scorera`, ' ', -1)), 1) AS `Goal Minute`
from goals;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bfa3ce8d77e87f5a2699321966cd843e)

Note that this work with strings should be done on your data *before* inserting it in your table, otherwise using your data from your table will be painful and inefficient.

Comment: Zakaria,  thanks. What I needed and you solved my problem quickly without complaining as above users. Thanks so much. Regards.